# Reliable way to only get the email text, excluding previous emails

Tags: python, django, email

I'm creating a basic system that allows users to reply to a thread on the website via email. However, most email clients include the text of the previous emails in their reply emails. This text is unwanted on the website.

Is there a reliable way in which I can extract only the new message, without prior knowledge about the earlier emails? I'm using the `email` class of Python.

---

### Example message:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

test message! This is the part I want.

On Thu, Mar 24, 2011 at 3:51 PM, <test@test.com> wrote:

> Hi!
>
> Herman just posted a comment on the website:
>
>
> From: Herman
> "Hi there! I might be interested"
>
>
> Regards,
> The Website Team
> http://www.test.com
>
```

This is a reply message from gmail, I'm sure other clients might do it differently. A good start would probably be to ignore the lines that start with `>`, but there could also be lines like that in between the new message, and then they probably should be kept. I'll also still have the content-type line and the date line.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134330/how-to-extract-email-message-body-without-signature-or-quoted-text however, it currently does not have any useful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formatting of email replies depend on the clients. There is no realiable way to extract the newest message without the risk of removing too much or not enough.

However, a common way to mark quotes is by prefixing them with `>` so lines starting with that character - especially if there are multiple at the very end or beginning of the email - are likely to be quotes.

But the `On Thu, Mar 24, 2011 at 3:51 PM, <test@test.com> wrote:` from your example is hard to extract. A line ending with a `:` right before a quote might indicate that it belongs to the quote, you cannot know that for sure - it could also be part of the new message and the colon is just a typo'd `.` (on german keyboards `:` is `SHIFT+.`).

Comment: It's a shame that there's no real reliable way, but the ideas you gave proved helpful, especially the point on German keyboards - thanks.

Comment: I'd agree there's no reliable way and there really should be but each client differs. We have been experimenting at CloudMailin with a way to include this parsing by default but we don't have anything that catches everything we want yet.

Answer (score 2):

The answer @LAMRIN TAWSRAS gave will work for parsing the text before the Gmail date expression only if a match is found, otherwise an error will be thrown. Also, there isn't a need to search the entire message for multiple date expressions, you just need the first one found. Therefore, I would refine his solution to use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
def get_body_before_gmail_reply_date(msg):
  body_before_gmail_reply = msg
  # regex for date format like "On Thu, Mar 24, 2011 at 3:51 PM"
  matching_string_obj = re.search(r"\w+\s+\w+[,]\s+\w+\s+\d+[,]\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+[:]\d+\s+\w+.*", msg)
  if matching_string_obj:
    # split on that match, group() returns full matched string
    body_before_gmail_reply_list = msg.split(matching_string_obj.group())
    # string before the regex match, so the body of the email
    body_before_gmail_reply = body_before_gmail_reply_list[0]
  return body_before_gmail_reply
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
import re
string_list = re.findall(r"\w+\s+\w+[,]\s+\w+\s+\d+[,]\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+[:]\d+\s+\w+.*", strings) # regex for On Thu, Mar 24, 2011 at 3:51 PM
res = strings.split(string_list[0]) # split on that match
print(res[0]) # get before string of the regex
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
def deleteForwardedMessagesFromMessage(message):
    nextMessage = re.split(r"\n.*[\,].*\<\s*.*>", message)[0]
    print(nextMessage)
    return nextMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for french/english emails :

> On Thu, Mar 24, 2011 at 3:51 PM, test@test.com wrote:

> Le mer. 28 avr. 2021 à 10:03, test.test@orange.com a écrit :

regex=r'\w+\s+\w+[,.]\s+(\w+\s+\d+|\d+\s+\w+)[,.]\s+\d+\s+(\w+|\à)\s+\d+[:]\d+(\s+\w+)?,?\s+(\s*<?\s*[a-zA-Z]*[._-]?[a-zA-Z]*[@]\w+[.]?\w{2,3}\s*>?;?\s*)(a écrit|wrote)\s*:'