# How to extract email message body, without signature or quoted text

Tags: email, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

What software can I use to process raw email text to remove the signature, quoted thread text, etc...

For example, here is an email. I would like to get just the "Thanks guys." text or more if there was more text there. I do not want the HTML signature (in the first red block) or the old emails that the person was replying to (in the second red block)

[image]

Comment: Any solutions found for this?  Maybe machine learning, LLMs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reliable way to only get the email text, excluding previous emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420402/reliable-way-to-only-get-the-email-text-excluding-previous-emails)

Answer (score -3):

You can try [Message.get_payload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload) from [email message handling package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html).

```
import email

with open('test.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

body = email.message_from_string(data)
if body.is_multipart():
    for payload in body.get_payload():
        print(payload.get_payload().strip())
else:
    print(body.get_payload().strip())
```

It outputs:

```
this is the body text
this is the attachment text
```

The `test.txt` file contains the following.

```
From: John Doe <example@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="XXXXboundary text"

This is a multipart message in MIME format.

--XXXXboundary text 
Content-Type: text/plain

this is the body text

--XXXXboundary text 
Content-Type: text/plain;
Content-Disposition: attachment;
        filename="test.txt"

this is the attachment text

--XXXXboundary text--
```

Comment: The test does only cover multipart not typical signature lines or quotes